# How to dynamically add data to a table via map/if or terinary operator in JSX

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-table

I am working with `material-ui/react` tables and I need to replace some static table data with some dynamic data from my web API.

I have the data, but I'm struggling with **JSX syntax**. I come from Java world so JSX is new to me and I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around some of the syntax and requirements when rendering. I've used server-side templates before so this should be easy, but I'm finding it very difficult.

I know JSX doesn't like if statements inside maps. I've seen recommendations to use a ternary operator (?) but I don't have an if/else scenario, only an if. Can someone help me to achieve my desired results and explain some JSX to me?

Here is what the table looked like before (credits to creative-tim):

```
<Table
  tableData={[
    [
      <img src={us_flag} alt="us_flag" key={"flag"} />,
      "USA",
      "2.920",
      "53.23%"
    ],
    ...
    [
      <img src={ro_flag} alt="us_flag" key={"flag"} />,
      "Romania",
      "600",
      "5.94%"
    ],
    [
      <img src={br_flag} alt="us_flag" key={"flag"} />,
      "Brasil",
      "550",
      "4.34%"
    ]
  ]}
/>
```

And here is what I'm trying to no avail to replace it with:

```
<Table tableData={
  {evtCounts.map(function (evtCount) {
    {sites.map(function (site) {
      if (site.IDX == evtCount.SiteID) {
        return ([{site.Name}, {evtCount.Percentage}]);
      }
    })}
  })}
}/>
```

Despite the obvious formatting issue (missing the external set of square brackets), I'm having trouble getting this to compile. JSX does not like my map statements for some reason. It just keeps telling me:

```
        ./src/views/Dashboard/Dashboard.js
      Line 197:31:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

      195 |                 <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={5}>
      196 |                   <Table tableData={
    > 197 |                     {evtCounts.map(function (evtCount) {
          |                               ^
      198 |                       {sites.map(function (site) {
      199 |                         if (site.IDX == evtCount.SiteID) {
      200 |                           return ([{site.Name}, {evtCount.Percentage}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notice points

- map need a return if you have `{}` after `=>` ([arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))
- you can use `&&` for [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
- `<></>` is a [react.fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)
- you can check the official document to find out what content is needed for `tableData` props

Below is a small sample for normal situation

```
<Table tableData={
  evtCounts.map(evtCount => 
    sites.map(site =>
      site.IDX === evtCount.SiteID &&
      <>
        <p>{site.Name}</p>
        <p>{evtCount.Percentage}</p>
      </>
    )
  )}
/>
```

Comment: The idea of "props" is new to me as well. Coming from a strongly typed language, everything had a clearly defined type. That was very syntactically helpful though! Thank you very much! I did find the && operator earlier. That's going to take some getting used to.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your answer because I think that put me on the right track. :)